# Invalid token #end - Struts Velocity

Tags: html, velocity

I placed the following code in enter-protein.vm

```xml
 <html>
      <head>
         <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
         <title>Insert title here</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <h1> Enter Protein VELOCITY </h1>

         #sform ("action = enter-protein")
         #stextfield ("name=enteredProtein")
         #ssubmit("value=Enter")
         #end
         <div>Amount entered: #sproperty ("value = enteredProtein")</div>
         <div> Total for the day : 100 grms  </div>
         <div> #sproperty ("value=goalText")</div>
      </body>
   </head>
</html>
```

I get an error at `#end` as

> Invalid token `#end`

I also included additional directories like commons-collections-3.2.jar, velocity-1.6.2.jar, velocity-tools-view.2.0.jar

Comment: After indenting the code, you'd discover that you have invalid HTML (a second  `</head>` closed after the body). That said, it's not clear what `#end` should close; finally, why are you calling the jars *"directories"* ? Heck

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: since you don't have loop why you want `#end`?. i removed end and look fine

Answer (score 0):

`#end` marks the end of a block started by one of `#if`, `#foreach`, `#macro`, or `#define`. Neither of these is used in the rest of the template, so there's no need for the `#end` used in the code. Simply remove it, and the error should be gone.

Perhaps you're trying to make `#sform` a macro with a body? In that case, it should be called as `#@sform`, but that isn't supported by Velocity 1.6, which you seem to be using.